# Apps to find local events

Tags: recommendations, vienna, budapest, mobile-apps, software

I will be traveling around Central Europe by the end of this month and I would like to know if you could recommend me any app for finding events been held in some particular city the same day that I check the app or the day after.

I am looking for something similar to **Fever** which works preferably in Vienna, Budapest and Bratislava. If it is an iOS app or a website it would be better, but android apps would be ok too.

P.S. I not sure if travel is the right place to ask this question.

Comment: Look at Meetup.com, I used it in London (although I only went to one and found my best friends here), it's a great method to meet people. Couchsurfing is a good place to find people who are in the area too for sight seeing.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I want. Those apps are focused in meeting people and for this particular travel I'm just interested in things to do. For instance, the apps that I've used in Spain let me know about the different concerts, theatre plays, art exhibitions, ... that are taking place that same day allowing me, in most cases, to buy the ticket from the same app (if it is not free). I will take a deeper look anyway :)

Comment: Most meetups are essentially that, doing things in that city, on that weekend with a bunch of people. But if that doesn't suit your purpose no harm :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been googling a bit these last few days and I found a website that seems helpful to me.

[Eventful](http://vienna.eventful.com/events/categories#!when=today) : It's a website that offers what I was looking for, allowing me to filter events by date (it's possible to filter just those events taking place today) and different categories and including links to buy the tickets for any of them. I will keep digging into it but it seems that I've found exactly what I wanted.

I will keep looking to see if I can find a mobile app that does the same function because the web feels clumsy in my phone.

Comment: I just checked Eventful. Nice, but for my current city, Santiago, it seems to only show major concerts. What about neighbourhood events?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a few apps like these, but they all focussed on only a few cities.

As a recommendation, use Facebook:

1. Go to http://facebook.com
2. Click 'Events' in the left column.
3. Scroll down and click 'Popular Events Nearby'.

Annoyingly, the resulting list is sorted by some vague popularity rating, not by date.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/de/cities/at/vienna)? A lot of the groups there are software or IT focused, but if you dig around a little you can also find some smaller outdoor or hiking groups, arts&crafts, special movie events, language groups etc. - at least in the bigger cities.

The website is mobile friendly, but i'm sure they also have an app.